# facebook pixel: PageView vs. ViewContent

Tags: facebook

Sorry if this has been asked many times but I really got confused on how to use facebook pixel.

I have a landing page (success page) where I want to track how many users have landed to that page.

I am confused between PageView and ViewContent.

In my case, what should I use so I can track the pixel?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook Pixel implicit PageView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36559028/facebook-pixel-implicit-pageview)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Facebook documentation here explains:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/api-reference#events

In the documentation it says:

> The default pixel code fires the PageView event, which can be used to
>   create Custom Audiences and custom conversions that match referral
>   URLs. This event should not be removed as it may cause disruption to
>   the aforementioned rules.

According to FB, the ViewContent event is for:

> When a key page is viewed such as a product page, e.g. landing on a
>   product detail page

Here is an example of the usage of ViewContent

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/api-reference#utilizing_params

Answer (score 10):

@Andrew's answer shows the [most useful Facebook page for events](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/api-reference#utilizing_params).

Watch out because there is another page that shows a similar list of events without even mentioning any parameters. It just says to do `fbq('track', 'ViewContent')` which is USELESS!

You must do the following to get useful data:

```
fbq('track', 'ViewContent', { content_name: 'Homepage' });
```

The `PageView` event just automatically sends the URL **and takes no parameters** and is part of the default configuration.

---

Also be sure to use the 'Test Events' panel to see in real time (instantly!) when your events come through.

[image]

Comment: This is useful too, even if you're not doing an SPA https://developers.facebook.com/ads/blog/post/2017/05/29/tagging-a-single-page-application-facebook-pixel/