# How PageView is counted in Facebook Pixel?

Tags: reactjs, facebook-pixel

I measure standard and custom Facebook events on my website. One of the very important event is `PageView`. My site is a React site, so I included: `react-facebook-pixel`

and this is how I measure:

```js
ReactPixel.pageView();
```

If I turn off this line `ReactPixel.pageView()`, I still can see values at PageView. How is it possible? Does PageView statistics shows only event when `ReactPixel.pageView();` is called, or it takes into account other things as well?

Answer (score 0):

[Facebook Pixel implicit PageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36559028/facebook-pixel-implicit-pageview)
is it helpful? As it states: `"I find that as soon as I init my pixel fbq('init', '1234567890');, a PageView event is being sent implicitly."`
edit: `fbq` is also implemented in `react-facebook-pixel` regardless what I posted is an `angular example`.